# celery: get function name by task id?

Tags: python, celery

I am using celery [`on_failure`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#handlers) handler to logging all failed tasks for debugging and analysis. And I want to know the task name(function name) of the failed task, how can I get that?

```
from celery import Task

class DebugTask(Task):
    abstract = True

    def after_return(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Task returned: {0!r}'.format(self.request))

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        func_name = get_func_name_by_task_id(task_id) # how do I do this?
        print "{} failed".format(func_name)           # expected out: add failed.

@app.task(base=DebugTask)
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

PS: I know there is `task_id`, but query function name by `task_id` every time is not fun,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick look at the documentation shows [`Task.name`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.name).

Comment: Thanks, looks like I over-thought this.