# Celery - how to get task name by task id?

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

Celery - bottom line: I want to get the task name by using the task id (I don't have a task object)

Suppose I have this code:

```
res = chain(add.s(4,5), add.s(10)).delay()
cache.save_task_id(res.task_id)
```

And then in some other place:

```
task_id = cache.get_task_ids()[0]
task_name = get_task_name_by_id(task_id) #how?
print(f'Some information about the task status of: {task_name}')
```

I know I can get the task name if I have a task object, like here: [celery: get function name by task id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183602/celery-get-function-name-by-task-id).
But I don't have a task object (perhaps it can be created by the task_id or by some other way? I didn't see anything related to that in the docs).

In addition, I don't want to save in the cache the task name. (Suppose I have a very long chain/other celery primitives, I don't want to save all their names/task_ids. Just the last task_id should be enough to get all the information regarding all the tasks, using .parents, etc)

I looked at all the relevant methods of AsyncResult and AsyncResult.Backend objects. The only thing that seemed relevant is backend.get_task_meta(task_id), but that doesn't contain the task name.
Thanks in advance

PS: AsyncResult.name always returns None:

```
result = AsyncResult(task_id, app=celery_app)
result.name #Returns None
result.args #Also returns None
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally found an answer.
For anyone wondering:
You can solve this by enabling `result_extended = True` in your celery config.
Then:

```
result = AsyncResult(task_id, app=celery_app)
result.task_name #tasks.add
```

Comment: Is `result.name` still None after `result_extended = True`?

Answer (score 3):

You have to enable it first in Celery configurations:

```
celery_app = Celery()
...
celery_app.conf.update(result_extended=True)
```

Then, you can access it:

```
task = AsyncResult(task_id, app=celery_app)
task.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following (pseudocode) should be enough:

```
app = Celery("myapp")  # add your parameters here
task_id = "6dc5f968-3554-49c9-9e00-df8aaf9e7eb5"
aresult = app.AsyncResult(task_id)
task_name = aresult.name
task_args = aresult.args
print(task_name, task_args)
```

Unfortunately, it does not work (I would say it is a bug in Celery), so we have to find an alternative. First thing that came to my mind was that Celery CLI has `inspect query_task` feature, and that hinted me that it would be possible to find task name by using the inspect API, and I was right. Here is the code:

```
# Since the expected way does not work we need to use the inspect API:
insp = app.control.inspect()
task_ids = [task_id]
inspect_result = insp.query_task(*task_ids)
# print(inspect_result)
for node_name in inspect_result:
    val = inspect_result[node_name]
    if val:
        # we found node that executes the task
        arr = val[task_id]
        state = arr[0]
        meta = arr[1]
        task_name = meta["name"]
        task_args = meta["args"]
        print(task_name, task_args)
```

Problem with this approach is that it works only while the task is running. The moment it is done you will not be able to use the code above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Sadly, aresult.name returns None

Comment: Weird, it should work. I can confirm that it does not... In that case what you can do is to inspect active/reserved tasks and find the name of the one with ID you have given... I do not like this workaround, but it is something to start with...

Comment: I think this is a bug, and should be reported!

Comment: Thanks for posting your second solution! I learned something new. Though, it doesn't help me with this problem, as the tasks might be in done state already.
I will definitely try to report this.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very clear from the docs for [celery.result.AsyncResult](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult) but not all the properties are populated unless you enable `result_extended = True` as per [configuration docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html?highlight=result_extended#result-extended):

> result_extended
>
> > Default: False
> >
> > > Enables extended task result attributes (name, args, kwargs, worker, retries, queue, delivery_info) to be written to backend.

Then the following will work:

```
result = AsyncResult(task_id)
result.name = 'project.tasks.my_task'
result.args = [2, 3]
result.kwargs = {'a': 'b'}
```

Also be aware that the rpc:// backend does not store this data, you will need Redis, or similar.  If you are using rpc, even with `result_extended = True` you will still get `None` returned.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good answer in this [code snippet](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3628#issuecomment-310650926).

If and when you have an instance of `AsyncResult` you do not need the task_id, rather you can simply do this:

```py
result # instance of AsyncResult
result_meta = result._get_task_meta()
task_name = result_meta.get("task_name")
```

Of course this relies on a private method, so it's a bit hacky. I hope celery introduces a simpler way to retrieve this - it's especially useful for testing.